# Second y axis with ggplot in R

Tags: r

I have a problem with ggplot with two y axis.
I got df1 with group of 2020 and 2022 bed elevation, and df2_sub with the changing of the bed with negative and positive value. I tried to plot them all in same plot using ggplot. It was working fine without second y axis. But it did not show the bar plot when I add the second y.
The first y axis lim (-25,0), and the second y lim (-1,1).
Could you check what wrongs with the code.
Thank you so much.
Here are the dataset and the code:

```
    dput(df2_sub)
structure(list(Distance = c(0, 1.002504622, 2.005009244, 3.007513866, 
4.010018489, 5.012523111, 6.015027733, 7.017532355, 8.020036977, 
9.022541599, 10.02504622, 11.02755084, 12.03005547, 13.03256009, 
14.03506471, 15.03756933, 16.04007395, 17.04257858, 18.0450832, 
19.04758782, 20.05009244, 21.05259707, 22.05510169, 23.05760631, 
24.06011093, 25.06261555, 26.06512018, 27.0676248, 28.07012942, 
29.07263404, 30.07513866, 31.07764329, 32.08014791, 33.08265253, 
34.08515715, 35.08766178, 36.0901664, 37.09267102, 38.09517564, 
39.09768026, 40.10018489, 41.10268951, 42.10519413, 43.10769875, 
44.11020337, 45.112708, 46.11521262, 47.11771724, 48.12022186, 
49.12272649, 50.12523111, 51.12773573, 52.13024035, 53.13274497, 
54.1352496, 55.13775422, 56.14025884, 57.14276346, 58.14526809, 
59.14777271, 60.15027733, 61.15278195, 62.15528657, 63.1577912, 
64.16029582, 65.16280044, 66.16530506, 67.16780968, 68.17031431, 
69.17281893, 70.17532355, 71.17782817, 72.1803328, 73.18283742, 
74.18534204, 75.18784666, 76.19035128, 77.19285591, 78.19536053, 
79.19786515, 80.20036977, 81.20287439, 82.20537902, 83.20788364, 
84.21038826, 85.21289288, 86.21539751, 87.21790213, 88.22040675, 
89.22291137, 90.22541599, 91.22792062, 92.23042524, 93.23292986, 
94.23543448, 95.2379391, 96.24044373, 97.24294835, 98.24545297, 
99.24795759), X2022 = c(-19.3654, -19.3659, -19.3664, -19.3669, 
-19.3674, -19.3678, -19.3683, -19.3688, -19.3693, -19.3698, -19.3702, 
-19.3707, -19.3712, -19.3717, -19.3721, -19.3709, -19.3697, -19.3685, 
-19.3673, -19.3661, -19.3649, -19.3637, -19.3625, -19.3613, -19.3601, 
-19.3589, -19.3577, -19.3565, -19.3553, -19.3541, -19.3529, -19.3517, 
-19.3506, -19.3494, -19.3482, -19.347, -19.3458, -19.3446, -19.3434, 
-19.3422, -19.341, -19.3398, -19.3386, -19.3374, -19.3362, -19.335, 
-19.3338, -19.3326, -19.3314, -19.3302, -19.329, -19.3278, -19.3266, 
-19.3254, -19.3242, -19.323, -19.3218, -19.3206, -19.3194, -19.3182, 
-19.317, -19.3158, -19.3146, -19.3134, -19.3122, -19.311, -19.3098, 
-19.3086, -19.3075, -19.3063, -19.3051, -19.3039, -19.3027, -19.3015, 
-19.3003, -19.2991, -19.2979, -19.2967, -19.2966, -19.2975, -19.2983, 
-19.2992, -19.3001, -19.301, -19.3019, -19.3027, -19.3036, -19.3045, 
-19.3054, -19.3062, -19.3071, -19.308, -19.3089, -19.3098, -19.3106, 
-19.3115, -19.3124, -19.3133, -19.3142, -19.315), X2023 = c(-20.3296, 
-20.3301, -20.3306, -20.3311, -20.3317, -20.3322, -20.3327, -20.3332, 
-20.3338, -20.3343, -20.3348, -20.3353, -20.3359, -20.3364, -20.3369, 
-20.3357, -20.3345, -20.3334, -20.3322, -20.3311, -20.3299, -20.3287, 
-20.3276, -20.3264, -20.3252, -20.3241, -20.3229, -20.3218, -20.3206, 
-20.3194, -20.3183, -20.3171, -20.3159, -20.3148, -20.3136, -20.3125, 
-20.3113, -20.3101, -20.309, -20.3078, -20.3067, -20.3055, -20.3043, 
-20.3032, -20.302, -20.3008, -20.2997, -20.2985, -20.2974, -20.2962, 
-20.295, -20.2939, -20.2927, -20.2915, -20.2904, -20.2892, -20.2881, 
-20.2869, -20.2857, -20.2846, -20.2834, -20.2823, -20.2811, -20.2799, 
-20.2788, -20.2776, -20.2764, -20.2753, -20.2741, -20.273, -20.2718, 
-20.2706, -20.2695, -20.2683, -20.2672, -20.266, -20.2648, -20.2637, 
-20.2636, -20.2645, -20.2655, -20.2664, -20.2673, -20.2682, -20.2692, 
-20.2701, -20.271, -20.2719, -20.2729, -20.2738, -20.2747, -20.2756, 
-20.2766, -20.2775, -20.2784, -20.2793, -20.2803, -20.2812, -20.2821, 
-20.283), evo = c(-0.964199999999998, -0.964200000000002, -0.964200000000002, 
-0.964199999999998, -0.964300000000001, -0.964400000000001, -0.964399999999998, 
-0.964400000000001, -0.964500000000001, -0.964499999999997, -0.964600000000001, 
-0.964600000000001, -0.964699999999997, -0.964700000000001, -0.9648, 
-0.9648, -0.964799999999997, -0.9649, -0.9649, -0.965, -0.965, 
-0.965, -0.9651, -0.9651, -0.9651, -0.965200000000003, -0.965199999999999, 
-0.965299999999999, -0.965299999999999, -0.965300000000003, -0.965399999999999, 
-0.965399999999999, -0.965299999999999, -0.965400000000002, -0.965400000000002, 
-0.965499999999999, -0.965499999999999, -0.965499999999999, -0.965600000000002, 
-0.965600000000002, -0.965699999999998, -0.965699999999998, -0.965700000000002, 
-0.965800000000002, -0.965799999999998, -0.965799999999998, -0.965900000000001, 
-0.965900000000001, -0.966000000000001, -0.965999999999998, -0.966000000000001, 
-0.966100000000001, -0.966100000000001, -0.966100000000001, -0.966200000000001, 
-0.966200000000001, -0.9663, -0.9663, -0.966299999999997, -0.9664, 
-0.9664, -0.9665, -0.9665, -0.9665, -0.9666, -0.9666, -0.9666, 
-0.966700000000003, -0.9666, -0.966699999999999, -0.966699999999999, 
-0.966700000000003, -0.966799999999999, -0.966799999999999, -0.966899999999999, 
-0.966899999999999, -0.966900000000003, -0.966999999999999, -0.966999999999999, 
-0.967000000000002, -0.967199999999998, -0.967200000000002, -0.967199999999998, 
-0.967200000000002, -0.967300000000002, -0.967399999999998, -0.967400000000001, 
-0.967399999999998, -0.967500000000001, -0.967600000000001, -0.967600000000001, 
-0.967600000000001, -0.967699999999997, -0.967700000000001, -0.9678, 
-0.9678, -0.9679, -0.967899999999997, -0.9679, -0.968), pos = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
)), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")


dput(df1)
structure(list(Distance = c(0, 1.002504622, 2.005009244, 3.007513866, 
4.010018489, 5.012523111, 6.015027733, 7.017532355, 8.020036977, 
9.022541599, 10.02504622, 11.02755084, 12.03005547, 13.03256009, 
14.03506471, 15.03756933, 16.04007395, 17.04257858, 18.0450832, 
19.04758782, 20.05009244, 21.05259707, 22.05510169, 23.05760631, 
24.06011093, 25.06261555, 26.06512018, 27.0676248, 28.07012942, 
29.07263404, 30.07513866, 31.07764329, 32.08014791, 33.08265253, 
34.08515715, 35.08766178, 36.0901664, 37.09267102, 38.09517564, 
39.09768026, 40.10018489, 41.10268951, 42.10519413, 43.10769875, 
44.11020337, 45.112708, 46.11521262, 47.11771724, 48.12022186, 
49.12272649, 50.12523111, 51.12773573, 52.13024035, 53.13274497, 
54.1352496, 55.13775422, 56.14025884, 57.14276346, 58.14526809, 
59.14777271, 60.15027733, 61.15278195, 62.15528657, 63.1577912, 
64.16029582, 65.16280044, 66.16530506, 67.16780968, 68.17031431, 
69.17281893, 70.17532355, 71.17782817, 72.1803328, 73.18283742, 
74.18534204, 75.18784666, 76.19035128, 77.19285591, 78.19536053, 
79.19786515, 80.20036977, 81.20287439, 82.20537902, 83.20788364, 
84.21038826, 85.21289288, 86.21539751, 87.21790213, 88.22040675, 
89.22291137, 90.22541599, 91.22792062, 92.23042524, 93.23292986, 
94.23543448, 95.2379391, 96.24044373, 97.24294835, 98.24545297, 
99.24795759, 0, 1.002504622, 2.005009244, 3.007513866, 4.010018489, 
5.012523111, 6.015027733, 7.017532355, 8.020036977, 9.022541599, 
10.02504622, 11.02755084, 12.03005547, 13.03256009, 14.03506471, 
15.03756933, 16.04007395, 17.04257858, 18.0450832, 19.04758782, 
20.05009244, 21.05259707, 22.05510169, 23.05760631, 24.06011093, 
25.06261555, 26.06512018, 27.0676248, 28.07012942, 29.07263404, 
30.07513866, 31.07764329, 32.08014791, 33.08265253, 34.08515715, 
35.08766178, 36.0901664, 37.09267102, 38.09517564, 39.09768026, 
40.10018489, 41.10268951, 42.10519413, 43.10769875, 44.11020337, 
45.112708, 46.11521262, 47.11771724, 48.12022186, 49.12272649, 
50.12523111, 51.12773573, 52.13024035, 53.13274497, 54.1352496, 
55.13775422, 56.14025884, 57.14276346, 58.14526809, 59.14777271, 
60.15027733, 61.15278195, 62.15528657, 63.1577912, 64.16029582, 
65.16280044, 66.16530506, 67.16780968, 68.17031431, 69.17281893, 
70.17532355, 71.17782817, 72.1803328, 73.18283742, 74.18534204, 
75.18784666, 76.19035128, 77.19285591, 78.19536053, 79.19786515, 
80.20036977, 81.20287439, 82.20537902, 83.20788364, 84.21038826, 
85.21289288, 86.21539751, 87.21790213, 88.22040675, 89.22291137, 
90.22541599, 91.22792062, 92.23042524, 93.23292986, 94.23543448, 
95.2379391, 96.24044373, 97.24294835, 98.24545297, 99.24795759
), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("X2022", 
"X2023"), class = "factor"), value = c(-19.3654, -19.3659, -19.3664, 
-19.3669, -19.3674, -19.3678, -19.3683, -19.3688, -19.3693, -19.3698, 
-19.3702, -19.3707, -19.3712, -19.3717, -19.3721, -19.3709, -19.3697, 
-19.3685, -19.3673, -19.3661, -19.3649, -19.3637, -19.3625, -19.3613, 
-19.3601, -19.3589, -19.3577, -19.3565, -19.3553, -19.3541, -19.3529, 
-19.3517, -19.3506, -19.3494, -19.3482, -19.347, -19.3458, -19.3446, 
-19.3434, -19.3422, -19.341, -19.3398, -19.3386, -19.3374, -19.3362, 
-19.335, -19.3338, -19.3326, -19.3314, -19.3302, -19.329, -19.3278, 
-19.3266, -19.3254, -19.3242, -19.323, -19.3218, -19.3206, -19.3194, 
-19.3182, -19.317, -19.3158, -19.3146, -19.3134, -19.3122, -19.311, 
-19.3098, -19.3086, -19.3075, -19.3063, -19.3051, -19.3039, -19.3027, 
-19.3015, -19.3003, -19.2991, -19.2979, -19.2967, -19.2966, -19.2975, 
-19.2983, -19.2992, -19.3001, -19.301, -19.3019, -19.3027, -19.3036, 
-19.3045, -19.3054, -19.3062, -19.3071, -19.308, -19.3089, -19.3098, 
-19.3106, -19.3115, -19.3124, -19.3133, -19.3142, -19.315, -20.3296, 
-20.3301, -20.3306, -20.3311, -20.3317, -20.3322, -20.3327, -20.3332, 
-20.3338, -20.3343, -20.3348, -20.3353, -20.3359, -20.3364, -20.3369, 
-20.3357, -20.3345, -20.3334, -20.3322, -20.3311, -20.3299, -20.3287, 
-20.3276, -20.3264, -20.3252, -20.3241, -20.3229, -20.3218, -20.3206, 
-20.3194, -20.3183, -20.3171, -20.3159, -20.3148, -20.3136, -20.3125, 
-20.3113, -20.3101, -20.309, -20.3078, -20.3067, -20.3055, -20.3043, 
-20.3032, -20.302, -20.3008, -20.2997, -20.2985, -20.2974, -20.2962, 
-20.295, -20.2939, -20.2927, -20.2915, -20.2904, -20.2892, -20.2881, 
-20.2869, -20.2857, -20.2846, -20.2834, -20.2823, -20.2811, -20.2799, 
-20.2788, -20.2776, -20.2764, -20.2753, -20.2741, -20.273, -20.2718, 
-20.2706, -20.2695, -20.2683, -20.2672, -20.266, -20.2648, -20.2637, 
-20.2636, -20.2645, -20.2655, -20.2664, -20.2673, -20.2682, -20.2692, 
-20.2701, -20.271, -20.2719, -20.2729, -20.2738, -20.2747, -20.2756, 
-20.2766, -20.2775, -20.2784, -20.2793, -20.2803, -20.2812, -20.2821, 
-20.283)), row.names = c(NA, -200L), class = "data.frame")

    min_first  <- min(df1$value) 
    max_first  <- max(df1$value)
    p <- ggplot() + 
      geom_line(data = df1, aes(x=Distance, y=value, color =variable),size=1) + 
      geom_col(data = df2_sub, aes(x=Distance, y=evo,fill=pos),size=1.55) + 
      scale_fill_discrete(name="",breaks=c("TRUE","FALSE"),labels=c("Increase(+)","Decrease (-)")) +
      scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~(. - min_first) *2/ (max_first - min_first)-1, name = "Bed evolution (m)")) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

Comment: We can't really answer without seeing your data. Could you perhaps include the output of `dput(df1)` and `dput(df2_sub)` in your question so we can test and verify solutions? As a rough guess, your bars are not appearing because bars can only be shown if the (primary) y axis limit includes 0. See what happens when you remove `limits` from `scale_y_continuous`. If that doesn't help, please make a _reproducible_ example. The output of a script is dependent on the data put into it, not just the code itself. Thanks.

Comment: Thank Allan, I just added some info for df1 and df2_sub. Dont know how to add the data set here.

Comment: If you type `dput(df1)` into your R console, you will get a copy-pasteable text version of your data set that allows others to use it in their console. You can put it in a code block in your question.

Comment: Anyway, I have transcibed your data, and simply removing the limits from scale_y_continuous shows the bars as I stated above.

Comment: Thanks Allan, got the bars but it is still link with the primary axis. I did try geom_bars then geom_line, the results was same.

Comment: The bars are _always_ tied to the primary axis. Adding a secondary axis doesn't change that. You need to perform some linear transformation on the bar's values to get them on the correct scale. The secondary axis is just an annotation that shows how the values should be interpreted. See my worked example below.

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat more subtle problem than it first appears. In order for the change in the value of the lines to be visible, we need to curtail the y axis between about -21 and -18. However, if we do this, then we will not see any bars. The reason for this is twofold. Firstly, the bars are not within the range [-21, -18], but secondly no bars are drawn if 0 is not included in the scale range. That means we need to curtail the y axis using `coord_cartesian` instead of `scale_y_continuous`.
We then need to perform some linesr transformation on the value of the bars so that their transformed values are within the range [-21, -18]. Adding a secondary axis won't do that - a secondary axis is simply an annotation on the side of the plot. We give it the formula to reverse the linear transformation we applied to our bars:

```r
ggplot(df1, aes(x = Distance)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = value, color = variable), linewidth = 1.5) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = (evo + 0.96)*200 - 17.5, fill = pos), alpha = 0.5, 
           data = df2_sub) + 
  scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = c(`TRUE` = "green4", `FALSE` = "red3"),
                    labels  = c("Increase(+)", "Decrease (-)"),
                    limits = c("TRUE", "FALSE")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("deepskyblue4", "gold")) +
  scale_y_continuous("Value",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ (.x + 17.5)/200 - 0.96, 
                                         name  = "Bed evolution (m)")) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-20.5, -18))
```

[image]